# Fix fuzziness for ElasticSearch/OpenSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm having issues trying to do a simple query, please see the following data:

Having this data:

```json
POST test/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Test Name"
}

POST test/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "TestName"
}
```

And this query:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "TestName",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this output:

```json
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.605183,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.605183,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "TestName"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why the output doesn't return both records?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was done with [elasticsearch edge n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), I also had to add filter lowercase to the analyzer.

Thanks @paulo !

```json
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "edge_ngram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/1
{
  "title": "Test Name"
}

POST test/_doc/2
{
  "title": "TestName"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.edge_ngram": {
        "query": "Test Name",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it returns the expected output:

```json
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.1782691,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.1782691,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Test Name"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.68817455,
        "_source": {
          "title": "TestName"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

Fizziness has limits in elasticsearch. The limit is on the Levenshtien distance, set to a max of 2.

That means you will not be able to match anything that is more than 2 edits away.

## To understand

```json
POST 77491663/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Test Name"
}

POST 77491663/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "TestName"
}

POST 77491663/_doc/3
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "TestNa"
}

GET 77491663/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "TestName",
        "fuzziness": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should give you

```json
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0925692,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "77491663",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0925692,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "TestName"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "77491663",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.7283795,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "TestNa"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## To Fix

You may want to look into [analyser capabilities](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

If you were to use [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for example you make it work.

Comment: I was able to make it work with ngram, but looks like only works if it is all uppercase or lowercase, which is something I can change, but I prefer doing insensitive queries.

Comment: You may need to add the lowercase processor ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it work, will update here soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you re using the default elasticsearch `analyzer` the `Test Name` value is splited and stored into the `inverted index` separately that means when you search with `TestName` value elasticsearch check if `TestName` match whit a level of fuzziness `Test` or match `Name` and not the phrase `Test Name` that is why you can't get the first document